# Searching for particular value of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I want to query for a particular value lets say "AYX" in some particular column of some particular table in a database.I need to get the list of tables and columns basically having value as "AYX"..How do I go for it?Is it possible? I am using SQL SERVER 2008

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you want to return any table/column that contains at least one row where the column value is "AYX"? Or do you want to return the actual data? Does it matter what the column name is, or just any column that contains a string?

Comment: @Aaron You are correct..I want to return any table/column that contains at least one row where the column value is "AYX"

Comment: You didn't see all of my questions. WHAT column? Any string column? A specific column name?

Comment: Just wanted to search all columns and all tables...i know the query will take time..but how do i write it

Comment: Did you try the answer I posted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(32) = N'AYX';


CREATE TABLE #results
(
    [column] NVARCHAR(768), 
    [value] NVARCHAR(MAX)
);

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += 'SELECT ''' 
    +  QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id])) 
    + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME([object_id])) 
    + '.' + QUOTENAME(name) + ''', ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ' FROM ' 
    + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id])) 
    + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME([object_id])) 
    + ' WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ' LIKE ''%' + @string + '%'';
    '
FROM sys.columns 
WHERE system_type_id IN (35, 99, 167, 175, 231, 239)
AND OBJECTPROPERTY([object_id], 'IsMsShipped') = 0;

INSERT #results EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

SELECT [column],[value] FROM #results;

DROP TABLE #results;
```

Comment: +1 - This is a very thorough answer, I would upvote it more if I could. I would recommend the op to visit this link first though. http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: I'm assuming this is for an internal process, not exposed to end users, so the typically warnings about SQL injection etc. can probably be suspended.

Answer (score 1):

@Aaron Bertrand had a very nice script.

I just want to point out that there is a free tool `SSMS Tools Pack` can search data in all table/views.

[SSMS Tools Pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features?f=4)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use dynamic/code generated query.

Have a look at `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` to get your list of columns in the database.

Restrict to appropriate datatypes with a WHERE clause on that table/view.

Code generate the queries to do the search: `SELECT '{TABLE_NAME}' AS TABLE_NAME, '{COLUMN_NAME}' AS COLUMN_NAME, COUNT(*) AS ROW_COUNT FROM {TABLE_NAME} WHERE {COLUMN_NAME} LIKE '%{SEARCH}%'`

`UNION ALL` the resulting queries together (add `WHERE ROW_COUNT <> 0` to an outer query)